# delete a DataTable row bound to a datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview

I have a `DataTable` bound to a `dataGridView` using the following code :

```
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ReducedColTable;
```

At some point i would like to move the selected rows into another Table.
So here is the loop :

```
   List<DataGridViewRow> rows = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows
                                      where !row.IsNewRow
                                      orderby row.Index
                                      select row).ToList<DataGridViewRow>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in rows)
        {
            DataRow newRow = dtarget.Rows.Add();
            newRow.SetField("artiste", item.Cells[0].Value);
            newRow.SetField("album", item.Cells[1].Value);
            newRow.SetField("song", item.Cells[2].Value);
            newRow.SetField("year", item.Cells[3].Value);
            newRow.SetField("file_path", item.Cells[4].Value);
            newRow.SetField("file_size", item.Cells[5].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        }
```

Ps : I didnt find a way to copy the row into the new table (`dtarget`) which is declared globally hence the approach col by col.

```
DataTable dtarget = new DataTable();
```

My issue is that the last line is removing the row from the DataGridView but not from the original table (`ReducedColTable`)

Any hint how to achieve this ?

Comment: Remove the record (Row) from the DataSource (your DataTable). If you need a DataTable identical to the original, then `Clone()` the original. You can get a DataRow object and copy it to the cloned DataTable.

Comment: well, what i want is to be able to move rows from the original to the target, so the clone wouldnt work right ?

Comment: You clone a DataTable to have an object with the same structure (and constraint). Then you can copy/move a DataRow from the original DT to the cloned when you need to. Not related to removing a DataRow, you still need to remove it from the DataSource, not the Control.

Comment: ok get it thanks, i'll try this to avoid filling the target dt col by col. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the `DataTable`’s `ImportRow` works well for this. If you set the grids `SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect` then you should be able to loop through the grids `SelectedRows` collection and “import” the selected row(s) into the other `DataTable`. Below is a simple example.

`dt` and `dt2` are two `DataTables` with similar schemas. `dt` is a data source for `datagridview1` and `dt2` is a data source to `datagridview2`. Initially, `dt` is filled with some data and `dt2` is empty. Once the user selects one or more rows, a button's click event initiates moving the selected rows from `dt` to `dt2`.

To start, a simple loop through the selected rows. A check if the “new row” is selected which we do not want to copy, therefore we ignore it. Next, get the “data bound” row from the data table in the form of a `DataRowView` object. Then we “import” that row into `dt2`, and finally removing the copied row from `dt`. I did not do a lot of testing on this however it appears to work as expected.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DataRowView drv;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows) {
    if (!row.IsNewRow) {
      drv = (DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem;
      dt2.ImportRow(drv.Row);
      dt.Rows.Remove(drv.Row);
    }
  } 
}
```

To make the example complete, drop two grids and button onto a form.

```
DataTable dt;
DataTable dt2;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dt = GetTable();
  dt2 = GetTable();
  FillTable(dt);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
  dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
}

private DataTable GetTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(string));
  return dt;
}

private void FillTable(DataTable dt) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    dt.Rows.Add("C0R" + i, "C1R" + i, "C2R" + i);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.